# How to write to a header based on column name in csv with python

Tags: python, csv

I contain a tsv file, and I am trying to print data I acquire to a specific header in my tsv file.

This is what my table looks like. Right now, I am trying to scan through some data, and print to the 1-generated, 1-chains, 2-generated, 2 chains, .... based on the number of matches I find.

[image: example]

The problem is, I need to print data to each generated column without printing to the first 3 columns. Also, I an trying to print to each column in a specific way. For the "generated" column, I want to print only to the generated column, and not the chains column when looking for generated data. Same for the chains column.

[image: example]

In the example, I need to print the first word which comes after REMARK 350 in line 1 "Author" and line 2 print the letter.

Desired Output:

[image: output]

Comment: It is difficult to comment upon this issue without knowing what the `pdb` files look like and how you would like to write the data to the `tsv` file. It would be helpful if you could update the question with a plaintext (no image) sample of the `tsv` file, of a `pdb` file and an example of the desired output. Also [biopandas](http://rasbt.github.io/biopandas/) might be a relevant module for your work.

Comment: hello, i updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first extracting the relevant data from the files into a list of dictionaries, and then creating the dataframe from that list:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob('./folder_name/*.pdb') #specify the path to your folder with pdb files to create a list of all files

all_data = [] #empty list to populate

for filename in files: #iterate over the files
  with open(filename, "r") as f:
    data = {'FILENAME': filename.split('.')[0]} #create dictionary to populate with data
    lines = f.read().splitlines() #create list of lines

    for line in lines: #iterate over lines
      if 'REMARK 350' in line:
        if 'BIOMOLECULE: ' in line:
          nr = int(line.rsplit(': ', 1)[1].strip()) #extract number
        elif 'AUTHOR DETERMINED BIOLOGICAL UNIT: ' in line:
          data[f'{nr}-generated'] = line.rsplit(': ', 1)[1].strip() #populate dict, key is dynamically generated from the number
        elif 'APPLY THE FOLLOWING TO CHAINS: ' in line:
          data[f'{nr}-chains'] = line.rsplit(': ', 1)[1].strip()
    data['BIOMOLECULES'] = list(range(1, nr+1)) #add list of biomolecules
  all_data.append(data) #append dict to list

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data) #create dataframe
```

Running this on two `pdb` files I got from github got me this output:

|  | FILENAME | 1-generated | 1-chains | 2-generated | 2-chains | BIOMOLECULES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4gjt | TETRAMERIC | A, B | MONOMERIC | C | [1, 2] |
| 1 | 2n0n_M1 | MONOMERIC | A |  |  | [1] |

Comment: I tried this. Is there a way to use pandas to simply search for each keyword in all of my files and print to each column based on column name?

Comment: Well that would be possible, but inefficient as it would require a lookup (iteration over the lines) for every single keyword search. In my example I iterate only once per file.

Comment: How should I specify the location of the file for line number 3? I tried putting the direct location, but then I got an error saying index out of range for nr = int(line.rsplit(': ', 1)[1].strip())

Comment: The example assumes all pdb files are in the same folder. Glob creates a list of files in the folder and loops over them. `glob('./folder_name/*.pdb')`: replace `./folder name/` with the path to the folder with pdb files.`*.pdb` indicated that glob should look for all files with the extension `.pdb`.

Comment: I got an error: nr = int(line.rsplit(': ', 1)[1].strip()) #extract number

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Apparently there is a line `REMARK 350 BIOMOLECULE` in a file without `:`+ number. I have updated the code so that it will only pick up lines with `:`.